# Кнопка "Мне нравится" Вконтакте

Tags: javascript, html, css, вконтакте

Все привет!
Мне нужно встроить кнопку "Мне нравится" которую любезно предостовляет Вконтакте. Проблема в том, что стилем она совершенно не вписываеться в мой дизайн.
Существуют ли методы радикального изменения внешнего вида кнопки, ну или хотя бы цвет подкорректировать?!

Comment: as is, as is!

Answer (score 3):

если кнопка "Мне нравится" визуально будет другой, пользователями она будет восприниматься тоже по-другому, поэтому не перестарайтесь.

Вот примерный код кнопки, исправляйте стилями или скриптами на здоровье:

```
<div class="like_wrap fl_l  checkbox_over" id="checkbox">
  <div class="like_left">
    <div class="like_left_border">
      <div class="icon iconV"></div>
      <div class="icon iconHeart"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="like_right">
    <div class="like_right_border fl_l">
      Мне нравится
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear like_bottom_shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Структуру кнопки сомневаюсь что изменить можно, но через ее css стили поменять можно. Просто где нибудь позже, после загрузки кнопки подргужаешь свой css, с теми классами что использует кнопка, новые стили добавляешь, что не нужно обнуляешь. Структуру кнопки, какие классы там используются можно посмотреть без проблем например  через firebug + ff.

Css для кнопки похоже подгружается отсюда - http://vk.com/css/widgets.css?45